# using hasFocus binding on table or div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

So basically I have this input text box:

```
 <input id="usersInputField" data-bind="hasFocus: isSearchInputFocused"/>
```

There is a table which pops whenever the input field has focus:

```
<div data-bind="visible: isSearchInputFocused">
   <table>
       <tbody data-bind="foreach: usersFromSearch">
           <!-- some info -->
       </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

...which works great. Although, I want the table to stay visible in case the user clicks on the div also.

Instead of the `isSearchInputFocused` observable in the table binding, I tried to use a `ko.computed` observable which returned true if the text box or the user table was focused and added a `hasFocus` binding on it, but that doesn't seem to work. I assume the `hasFocus` binding has priority over the `click` binding.

How can I keep the div open while either the table or the input have focus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A table isn't focusable by default, so that your first idea will not work. However, if you add a `tabindex` attribute, you can safely set the focus on the table. Thus, if you do so, you can use a focus observable for each element, and a computed which determines if either of them is focused to keep the div visible.

```js
var vm = {
  inputHasFocus: ko.observable(),
  tableHasFocus: ko.observable(),
};

// Don't take completing a model like this as a good practice:
vm.somethingHasFocus = ko.pureComputed(function() {
  var inputHasFocus = vm.inputHasFocus(); // ensures subscription
  var tableHasFocus = vm.tableHasFocus(); // ensures subscription
  return  inputHasFocus || tableHasFocus;
}, vm);

ko.applyBindings(vm);

// IE Hack
$('table *').on('click', function() { vm.tablehasFocus(true); })
```

```css
table {
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-collapse: true;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

*:focus {
  border-color: #FF0000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
  outline: none;
}

div {
  background-color: silver;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input tabindex="0" type="text" data-bind="hasFocus: inputHasFocus"/>


<table tabindex="1" data-bind="hasFocus: tableHasFocus">
  <tr>
    <td>I'm a table cell</td>
    <td>I'm another</td>
  <tr>
</table>

<div data-bind='visible: inputHasFocus'>Input has focus</div>
<div data-bind='visible: tableHasFocus'>Table has focus</div>
<div data-bind='visible: somethingHasFocus'>Something has focus</div>
```

*NOTE: as usual IE has a strange behavior: at least IE10 allows to focus on a table cell. The solution included in the script it's a hack. There are smarter options:*

- *create a custom binding `elementOrDescendantHasFocus`, which should not be too difficult: you can use delegated event handling to detect the focus events in the table or children*
- *create an array of hasFocus for each table cell, and a computed that depends on them all (I'd rather implement the hack)*
- *make the cells unfocusable by adding a negative `tabindex` attribute to them*

*So, if you have to support IE (at least IE10), choose any of these solutions, including the hack. In Chrome and Firefox there is no such problem*

Comment: Thank you so much for all the answers! I decided to go with this one as the table stays visible only when the table itself or the input field is focused.

I just added " data-bind='visible: inputHasFocus() || tableHasFocus()' " on my div and now works like a charm! Cheers!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. However, including expressions in the bindings "is forwned upon" ;) You'd rather create a pureComputed which depends on both properties, and use it in the binding. If you get used soon to make these things in the view model you won't have temptations to do tha complex bindings in the future. And I can assure that when you start using complex bindings things get complicated. Besides, you cannot debug them as easyly as if you're using a viemodel  computed.

Comment: I've discovered that IE10 has a problem. I've updated my answer

Comment: YES! I also need the IE support.
I tried the hack first, but I get a 'Object doesn't support property or method 'tableHasFocus'. Neither did the negative tabindex solution work me.
And I didn't get into custom bindings yet.
So I implemented the 'hasFocus on every cell' method.
Thanks a bunch! I'm in your debt :)

Comment: My bad. I made a typo when using the IE hack!

Answer (score 1):

idk if you want to do it this way, but you can make it so the table opens on focus of the input and stays open until you close it.

```js
// Here's my data model
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    
    self.focusMePlease = ko.observable(false);
    self.focusMePlease.subscribe(function() {
     if (self.focusMePlease() == true) {
         self.isSearchInputFocused(true);
        }
    });
    self.isSearchInputFocused = ko.observable(false);
    
    self.close = function() {
     self.isSearchInputFocused(false);
    };
    
};
 
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```css
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script><input id="usersInputField" data-bind="hasFocus: focusMePlease"/>
<br/><br/>
<div data-bind="visible: isSearchInputFocused">
   <table>
       <tr><td>stuff</td><td>stuff</td></tr>
   </table>
    <button data-bind="click: close">X</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can solver this question using focus event, like fallowing example:

http://jsbin.com/jewozilofe/edit?html,js,output